# What is the number of posible combinations of a given set of numbers when their order is irrelevant?

Tags: combinatorics

Say that we have a given set $S$ of numbers which do not repeat. We want to know how many subsets $B$ of $S$ can be formed were in the subset $B$ there are only $n$ numbers. The order of numbers are irrelevant in the subset, which means that if a subset has the same numbers than another subset then it counts as the same subset. Therefore, the question is how many subsets $B$ are there in the set $S$ ?

Comment: Actually, i didn't understand what it means"were in the subset B there are only n numbers." Anyways, i will proceed as per my discretion. Two ways, either consider combinations $ C(n,0)+C(n,1)+....+C(n,n)=2^n$ or Simply for each element consider that there are two choices so it will again be 2.2.2.....2=$2^n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is precisely what the meaning of "$n$ choose $k$" is all about! Given a set of $n$ objects (or distinct numbers in this case) the number of ways to pick $k$ of them without order mattering (or to choose a subset of size $k$) is $$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

Now if we want the number of *all* subsets of a particular set of size $n$, what we would do from here is take the sum $\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}$ and what we get is actually $2^n$! There are multiple ways of proving this fact; my personal favorite relies on applying the Binomial Theorem to $(1+1)^n$ but that's just me.